# Is it possible to pull public courtroom records about cases given a specific attorney?

Tags: court-records

Given a specific attorney (name/state, bar number, whatever) in the US, is it possible to find public court records of cases they have handled? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to find public court records of cases they have
>   handled? If so, how?

It depends how far each court has gotten in its implementation of information systems for public use. For instance, various trial courthouses in Michigan have a [webpage](https://tcweb.ewashtenaw.org/PublicAccess/Search.aspx?ID=200) where cases can be searched by attorney's name or bar number. The equivalent in Michigan appellate and supreme corrupts (errata: should read "courts") is [this website](http://courts.mi.gov/opinions_orders/case_search/pages/default.aspx).

That trial court in its webpage only displays the case history, not the actual records. The webpage of the appellate & supreme courts displays the contents of the opinions and orders, in addition to the docket history.

Comment: I see. So would searches have to be conducted by state, or by court? Or does it just depend. If by court, would a reasonable approach be to look up which courts a given attorney serves in, then contact those courts for info? For example, if an attorney is in Texas, the State Bar of Texas has a web site that lists “courts of admittance” for each attorney.

Comment: Made a PACER account. All the courts I wanted to search were on there. Bingo.

Comment: @JasonC Good! I was not sure about PACER. Glad it worked for you. Regarding your follow-up question, it is not that a lawyer needs admittance in each county trial court of a state. As long as he is licensed in a state, he can litigate in any courthouse (trial, appellate, and I believe supreme) of that state.